# I can't get video on youtube by channel.Why?

Tags: c#, wpf, youtube, youtube-api

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<List<ViewModel.YoutubeVideo>> GetYoutubeMusic()
    {
        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            ApiKey = "....",
            ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
        });


        var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Channels.List("snippet");
        searchListRequest.Id= "UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ";
        searchListRequest.MaxResults = 25;



        //Call the search.list method to retrieve results...
        var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();
        List<ViewModel.YoutubeVideo> arrays = new List<ViewModel.YoutubeVideo>();
        foreach (var searchResult in searchListResponse.Items)
        {
            product = new ViewModel.YoutubeVideo();
            product.id = searchResult.Id;
            product.Name = searchResult.Snippet.Title;
            product.Thumb100Uri = searchResult.Snippet.Thumbnails.Default.Url;
            product.Thumb200Uri = searchResult.Snippet.Thumbnails.Medium.Url;
            arrays.Add(product);

        }

        return arrays;
    }
```

just be get information from this channel but no video...
I don't understand about that. Please to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not calling the search.list method. You are calling the channels.list method in your code.

But if you already have the id of the channel, you should just [retrieve that channel's uploaded videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/videos#videos-retrieve-uploads).